# Replace non-zero values of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like below sample data.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(BranchCode = structure(c(9L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 
6L, 8L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("BU", "CA", "GT", "IN", 
"LM", "OX", "QC", "SR", "TD", "WG", "YV"), class = "factor"), 
    Requirement = c(0L, 5L, 12L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 10L, 
    0L), Availabile = c(3L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 
    6L), Alternative = c(9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 
    0L, 5L), Complex = c(3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 2L, 0L, 
    6L, 3L), Level1 = c(0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), Level2 = c(4L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 18L, 0L, 3L, 
    5L)), .Names = c("BranchCode", "Requirement", "Availabile", 
"Alternative", "Complex", "Level1", "Level2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

I need to replace all non-zero values with numeric 1. I can do this in two ways.

1. Using one column at a time to replace like below. Then i have to change column names every time.

   `df$Requirement[df$Requirement != 0] <- 1`
2. I can write a basic `for` loop and replace based on the condition, by going through index.

But both process taking time for me because everytime columns or rows will be increasing(sometimes 200 columns and 20000 rows). So i want to do this process on whole dataframe at a time. Like without replacing column after column or going by index of for loop on dataframe, i need to replace wherever there is a nonzero numeric value with a numeric 1. Something like below(But not working).

```
df[which(df[2:7] != 0)] <- 1
```

The final dataframe will look like below.

```
> df
   BranchCode Requirement Availabile Alternative Complex Level1 Level2
1          TD           0          1           1       1      0      1
2          GT           1          1           0       1      1      0
3          CA           1          0           0       1      0      0
4          BU           1          1           0       1      0      1
5          WG           0          0           1       0      1      1
6          OX           0          1           1       0      0      1
7          SR           1          0           1       1      1      1
8          YV           0          0           1       1      0      1
9          IN           1          1           0       0      0      0
10         LM           1          1           0       1      0      1
11         QC           0          1           1       1      0      1
```

A solution or suggestion would be great.

Comment: `df[df != 0] <- 1`

Comment: @sotos, Thaks for taking time to look into it. Your suggestion is doing great but it is making all other non numeric columns into `NA`.Do i have to do any additional process apart from copying the respective columns from original df?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
df[-1] <- as.integer(df[-1] != 0)
df
#   BranchCode Requirement Availabile Alternative Complex Level1 Level2
#1          TD           0          1           1       1      0      1
#2          GT           1          1           0       1      1      0
#3          CA           1          0           0       1      0      0
#4          BU           0          1           0       1      0      1
#5          WG           0          0           1       0      1      0
#6          OX           0          1           1       0      0      1
#7          SR           1          0           1       1      1      1
#8          YV           0          0           1       1      0      1
#9          IN           1          1           0       0      0      0
#10         LM           1          1           0       1      0      1
#11         QC           0          1           1       1      0      1
```

---

If you have more than one non-numeric column and need to find their positions first you could do

```
numeric_cols <- vapply(df, is.numeric, logical(1))
df[numeric_cols] <- as.integer(df[numeric_cols] != 0)
df
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe just one line of code resolved my issue. Its doing wonders for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1[-1] <- + sapply(df1[-1], as.logical)

#   BranchCode Requirement Availabile Alternative Complex Level1 Level2
#1          TD           0          1           1       1      0      1
#2          GT           1          1           0       1      1      0
#3          CA           1          0           0       1      0      0
#4          BU           1          1           0       1      0      1
#5          WG           0          0           1       0      1      1
#6          OX           0          1           1       0      0      1
#7          SR           1          0           1       1      1      1
#8          YV           0          0           1       1      0      1
#9          IN           1          1           0       0      0      0
#10         LM           1          1           0       1      0      1
#11         QC           0          1           1       1      0      1
```

---

- When using as.logical every 0 gets `FALSE` (0) every `n >= 1` gets `TRUE` (1)
- Prepending a `+` will type cast to integers.

Comment: Wonderful solution. Thank you for your time and solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just an add-on to previous answers.

```
df[-1] <- as.numeric(df[-1] != 0)
df[-1] <- as.numeric(df[-1] != 0, as.logical)
df[-1] <- as.numeric(as.logical(df[-1] != 0))
```